# Copying Value of a pointer to a variable, Pointer is passed as an argument C Program

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, pass-by-reference

```
int NJOBS=0;

struct Jobs{
    char *jname;
    int btime;
    int priority;
    int order;
}Job[10];

int cmd_run(int nargs, char **args) {    
    NJOBS++;

    Job[NJOBS].order=NJOBS;

    int bt = atoi(args[2]);    
    int pri = atoi(args[3]);

    Job[NJOBS].btime=bt;    
    Job[NJOBS].priority=pri;    
    Job[NJOBS].jname=args[1];    
}
```

I have a structure to carry job Details. A dispatcher function is passing arguments(args) from commandline to cmd_run function.
args in cmd_run will have something like this "Jobname 10 1".
I need to copy Jobname to Job[NJOBS].jname, while I am able to copy integer variables but string variables are not being copied. I also tried using a local cont char array and tried copying from argument to local variable it still does not work.
Please provide suggestions.
Help is much appreciated.

Thank you much!

Comment: There is no *pass-by-reference* in C. It's all *pass-by-value*. Passing a pointer is just a way of passing the address to something by value, and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you know the maximum length of jname, use a char array instead of char pointer and copy the input into your structure using [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) or the bounded [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/). If not, use dynamic memory allocation for pointer and use strcpy on it. You should remember to take care of the allocated memory after its purpose is done.

```
Job[NJOBS].jname = (char*)malloc(strlen(args[1])+1);
strcpy(Job[NJOBS].jname,args[1]);

//... 
//... 
//...

free(Job[NJOBS].jname);
```

As pointed out by Pablo, increment NJOBS only when you have filled the zero-th index. Else, if you were to uses Job[NJOBS] to fill 10 datasets, it will cause heap corruption.

Answer (score 0):

`Job[NJOBS].jname=args[1];` only copies the pointer, depending on how `argv` was initialized, this pointer may become invalid in the feature. You should allocate memory first for the string, then use `strcpy`.

```
Job[NJOBS].jname = malloc(strlen(args[1]) + 1);
if(Job[NJOBS].jname == NULL)
{
    // error handling
}

strcpy(Job[NJOBS].jname, args[1]);
```

And you should do `NJOBS++;` at the end of the function, not at the beginning,
and you should check that `NJOBS` does not get greater than 10, otherwise you
are accessing `Job` out of bounds:

```
int cmd_run(int nargs, char **args) {
    if(NJOBS >= sizeof Job / sizeof Job[0])
        return 0;

    ...

    NJOBS++;
    return 1;
}
```

Also your `cmd_run` is a function that must return an `int`, you are not
returning anything, otherwise the function should be `void cmd_run(int nargs, char **args);`

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! helped me solve another issue too.